# SHGetFolderPathAndSubDir not returning directory with C: drive;

Tags: c++, winapi, directory

I am working with creating directories and when using [SHGetFolderPathAndSubDir();](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpathandsubdira) The function was giving me the correct directory except the `'C'` was replaced with a `NULL` character

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Shlobj.h>
#include <Shlobj_core.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    TCHAR leaderboardPath[MAX_PATH];
    TCHAR leaderboardPathAppend[] = L"\\Tetris";

    SHGetFolderPathAndSubDir(NULL, CSIDL_APPDATA, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, leaderboardPathAppend, leaderboardPath);
    CreateDirectory(leaderboardPath, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

When I ran the code leaderboardPath[] would contain the correct directory except `leaderboardPath[0] == NULL;` instead of `leaderboardPath[0] == 'C';`

Comment: From the documentation: "`pszPath`: This string is empty when the function returns an error code." "Empty" for a nul-terminated string means that the very first character is NUL. Check the return value, your call is failing. Possibly due to this (from that same documentation page): "`pszSubDir`: If you are not creating a new directory, this must be an existing subdirectory or the function returns an error." And earlier: "You can force creation of a folder with `SHGetFolderPathAndSubDir` by combining the folder's `CSIDL` with `CSIDL_FLAG_CREATE`"

Comment: it returns HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND) : The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: [Read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpathandsubdirw) carefully; all the answers are there.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik what does it mean by combine, does it mean `||` it together or something else

Comment: change `CSIDL_APPDATA` to `CSIDL_APPDATA | CSIDL_FLAG_CREATE`

Comment: thank you, i haven't been coding in c++ for super long and I haven't used flags that much